# Karaf bundle is not starting

Tags: osgi, bundle, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am trying to install cxf feature in Karaf. It throws the following error:

```
karaf@root> features:install cxf-commands
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.1.0
    in feature(s) cxf-core-3.1.0: Activator start error
    in bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-core [515].
```

Note: All the dependent features and bundles are installed. No clue except this error.

Comment: What version of karaf are you using? I successfully installed the cxf-commands on karaf 4.0.5 with
`feature:repo-add cxf 3.1.0`
`feature:install cxf-commands`

Comment: I am using Karaf 2.3.4

Comment: Any idea on Activator start error?

Comment: Without more info, no sorry. Anything in the logfile? Some missing dependencies? What if you update the version of cxf-core?

Comment: What is your karaf version?

Comment: I'm using Karaf 2.3.4